# How to make a column as valid time datatype in hive?

Tags: hadoop, time, types, hive, hdfs

I have time column as string in hdfs file. When i create external table in hive for the same, I would like **to assign valid time data type for that column in hive.** How to make a column as valid time data type in hive?

Answer (score 0):

you can create table with `timestamp` datatype for time column.

```
create table mytable(id string ,time timestamp) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

And loading data statement:

```
`load data local inpath '/root/workspace/timedata' overwrite into table` mytable;
```

Table structure:

```
describe mytable;    

+-----------+------------+----------+
| col_name  | data_type  | comment  |
+-----------+------------+----------+
| id        | string     |          |
| time      | timestamp  |          |
+-----------+------------+----------+
```

OR

you can cast the column with in `timestamp` datatype

```
select id,cast(time as timestamp) time from mytable;
```